# React native margin: 'auto' working on web but not on device

Tags: react-native, flexbox, expo, margin

I am building an application which uses react native on expo dev. I am trying to add a button in the top left corner which is adjacent to some text o the right hand side, I have used `marginRight: 'auto'` for this and it does display as expected on the web version but on the app version on Android it appears centered as if the margin styling is ignored, any solutions?

```
<View style={styles.header}>
  
  <View style={styles.headerTop}>
    <Text style={styles.headerText}>Question {currentQuestion+1}/{questions.length}</Text>
    <TouchableOpacity 
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Home")}
      style= {styles.exitButton}
      >
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Exit</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    <Text style={styles.timer}>{timer}</Text>
  </View>

    header: {
    flexGrow: 0,
    padding: 8,
  },
  headerTop: {
    flexDirection: 'row-reverse',
  },
  headerText: {
    fontSize: 24,
    textAlign: 'right',
  },
exitButton: {
    padding: 12,
    paddingHorizontal: 12,
    backgroundColor: '#1BA7F9',
    borderRadius: 12,
    marginRight: 'auto',
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 20,
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have specified 'row-reverse' for header-top

```
headerTop: {
    flexDirection: 'row-reverse',
  },
```

So, instead of `marginRight: 'auto',` try using `marginLeft: 'auto',`

```
exitButton: {
        padding: 12,
        paddingHorizontal: 12,
        backgroundColor: '#1BA7F9',
        borderRadius: 12,
        marginLeft: 'auto',
      },
```

This should fix the issue. I tried it in the emulator and works fine. Attaching the screenshot.

[image]